# Fillable Pdf - responsive font size

Tags: pdf, textfield, acrobat, adobe-indesign, responsive

- with InDesign, or Acrobat knowledge

I have a question for you about making a Fillable Pdf form with responsive font size in the Text Fields. Now I am creating a corporate badge with a fix size text field on the cover, yet should include worker names with variable name lengths.

So my client asked me if I could make a Text Field on the cover with a feature, so the field could dynamically reduce the font size in it, to fit the size of the names to the length of the Text Field. So in this way we can display any names if the font size is a variable and connected to the length of the Text Field somehow.

I am graphic design professional, but mostly experienced with Illustrator and Photoshop, AfterEffects in the field of design and now I am just gaining typographical skills in InDesign and Acrobat about Fillable Pdf forms. I have seen dozens of [tutorials](http://www.lynda.com/InDesign-tutorials/Creating-PDF-Forms-InDesign/126118-2.html) and now I have a viable interactive text field, but if the name in it is too long, you cannot type the full name, or otherwise if I turn on the scrollable text field feature, I can't see the whole name displayed in the text field, because it's scrolled as many characters toward from the beginning as longer was the text compared to the length of the Text Field. So I am sure the solution will be outside of the Buttons and Forms Panel if we speak about Indesign, but I also would be glad if I could get any reply from Acrobat professionals as well! So now I am still caught in this situation and searching for the answer on the web and if I find it, I am sure I will share it! Otherwise if you have any ideas or questions about my problem feel free to share your viewpoint, I will be around!

Thank you for your attention and I wish you a great workflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Acrobat, get to the Field Properties dialog, Appearance tab, and set the font size to Automatic.

Comment: Thank you for your attention! This is suuuuper!
Cheers!

Comment: where is field properties dialogue? screenshot maybe?